# "dictionary doesn't contain key" even though the key is present in the dictionary in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, features, sentinel-5p

I am trying to retrieve the pollution data from Sentinel 5P. When trying to do so even though the key is present I am unable to get it by getting the error.

> FeatureCollection (Error)
> Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density.

Here I am sharing the total code

```
var region = nuapada;
var img_co = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CO').select('CO_column_number_density');
var img_no2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2').select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density');
var img_so2 =  ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2').select('SO2_column_number_density');


var img_map = img_no2.filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-06-01', '2019-08-01'));

var img_map_mean = img_map.mean();

var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.0005,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
var img_image = img_map_mean.clip(region);
Map.addLayer(img_image, band_viz, 'S5P O3');
Map.centerObject(region);

print (img_image);

var stats = img_image.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry: region,
   scale: 5000,
});

print(stats);

 var pr_monthlydata = ee.List.sequence(0, 7-1).map(function(n) {
  var start = ee.Date('2019-06-01').advance(n, 'day');
  var end = start.advance(6, 'day');


  var img_map_f_co = img_co.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end));
  var img_mean_f_co = img_map_f_co.mean();
  var img_img_f_co = img_mean_f_co.clip(region);

  var stats_co = img_img_f_co.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 5000,
  });


  var img_map_f_no2 = img_so2.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end));
  var img_mean_f_no2 = img_map_f_no2.mean();
  var img_img_f_no2 = img_mean_f_no2.clip(region);

  var stats_no2 = img_img_f_no2.reduceRegion({
     reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
     geometry: region,
     scale: 5000,
   });



  var img_map_f_so2 = img_so2.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end));
  var img_reducer_f_so2 = img_map_f_so2.mean();
  var img_img_f_so2 = img_reducer_f_so2.clip(region);

  var stats_so2 = img_img_f_so2.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry: region,
   scale: 5000,
 });


 var f = ee.Feature(null, {
   'CO': stats_co.get('CO_column_number_density'),
   'NO2': stats_no2.get('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density'),
   'SO2': stats_so2.get('SO2_column_number_density'),
   });

   return f;
});

  var prMonths = ee.FeatureCollection(pr_monthlydata)
  print(prMonths);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step when debugging code should be to find information that checks where your assumptions went wrong. You assume that `tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density` should be present, but the error says it doesn't. Let's find out what's there instead. In your code you have:

```js
var pr_monthlydata = ee.List.sequence(0, 7-1).map(function(n) {
  ...

  var f = ee.Feature(null, {
    'CO': stats_co.get('CO_column_number_density'),
    'NO2': stats_no2.get('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density'),
    'SO2': stats_so2.get('SO2_column_number_density'),
  });

  return f;
});
```

We can bypass the error and get a look at what keys are actually present by simply removing the `.get`s:

```js
  var f = ee.Feature(null, {
    'CO': stats_co,
    'NO2': stats_no2,
    'SO2': stats_so2,
  });
```

Then, the properties in the collection will be

```json
      "properties": {
        "CO": {
          "CO_column_number_density": 0.02539985420768159
        },
        "NO2": {
          "SO2_column_number_density": 0.000026588702898291228
        },
        "SO2": {
          "SO2_column_number_density": 0.000026588702898291228
        }
      }
```

So, there *isn't* a `tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density` but there *is* a `SO2_column_number_density`. This suggests that there's a place where data for SO2 was used where you wanted NO2. Looking at the code for such a case, I find this line above:

```js
  var img_map_f_no2 = img_so2.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end));
```

Change `img_so2` to `img_no2` and your code will succeed.